# Knn best accuracy with k = 20

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a big database with 40k recors and 2 classification classes. In this big database the 76% of records belong to the first class.

I've used a 70-30 split partition with stratified sampling, and the K-nn gives the best accuracy on k = 20.

1) Is it too big value for k ?

2) Is it possible that this big value for k is due to the disproportion of the 2 classes in the database , even if i used a stratified sampling ?

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not a devastatingly large number, especially given that you have a large dataset. Class imbalance has an effect on k-NN but if you are satisfied with your classifier's performance then you do not have to try fixing this imbalance (oversampling, undersampling, combinations...). Just make sure your classifier achieves the highest accuracy while maximizing other metrics such as f1-score or recall for the minority class. And do not forget to normalize your data before knn. You would not want one feature to dominate the distance between two instances.